# Cannot find module 'discord.js', console reporting

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, replit

I am very new using discord's javascript
This is also my first time posting on stackoverflow!
Anyway
Here's the full error

```
Error: Cannot find module 'discord.js'
Require stack:
- /home/runner/multiple-purpose-discord-bot-like-carlbot/xp.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/multiple-purpose-discord-bot-like-carlbot/xp.js:1:17)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/home/runner/multiple-purpose-discord-bot-like-carlbot/xp.js' ]
}
```

To my limited knowledge, this is either i made a typo
OR some package is outdated, [here's the full packages list](https://ghostbin.me/63722f0fcd5d1)

I also suspect that i incorrectly implemented the amethyste-api i am using, [here's my code](https://ghostbin.me/63722fba25326)
It's in a config file, should've i put `const mySecret = process.env['ame']` in the main file instead?, I do need it to be in the config for ease of access

npm install discord.js (manually through console/shell)

did do some stuff but stil didn't work

npm xp.js (manually through console/shell)

this is what i am supposed to run on start manually, that what gives the error

Comment: Please add a minimum reproducible example that we can use to help you further. With no code, we can't see how you are importing the package.

Answer (score 0):

You could run the following commands one after the other:

```
`npm init`
```

and then

```
`npm i discord.js`
```

Comment: Alternatively, to save time and space, `npm init -y && npm i discord.js --save`